# ¿Por qué al ejecutar el comando "npm start" de create-react-app no me funciona como debería dentro del entorno de WSL?

Tags: reactjs, windows, wsl

Tengo un proyecto de práctica creado con create-react-app, el cual lo inicie en el entorno de WSL (utilizo Ubuntu como distro) y al correr el comando "npm start", no me arroja ningún error en la consola pero, al momento de guardar para hacer actualizaciones, no se ven reflejadas en mi localhost, también me he dado cuenta que para levantar el servidor de desarrollo, se tarda unos 5 minutos en promedio (y eso sin tener nada más que todos los archivos iniciales de create-react-app).

Intente de iniciar el proyecto en el entorno de Windows y la consola tampoco me arroja ningún error pero, a diferencia del proyecto iniciado en WSL, al correr el comando "npm start", este me crea el servidor rápidamente y al hacer cambios, estos se actualizan automáticamente en el localhost al guardar a mi proyecto.

¿Alguien tiene o tuvo este mismo problema o sabrían como solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.0

Comment: ¿Qué tal esta [guía de instalación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/react-on-wsl)? saludos

Comment: ¡Saludos! Lo estuve leyendo pero, realmente son los mismo pasos que sigo.  Probaré urilizando otra distro para ver si no podría ser eso también el problema.

Comment: **(ACTUALIZACIÓN)** Tampoco fue problema de la distro, definitivamente (por algún motivo que desconozco), no me corre correctamente los scripts de create-react-app en el entorno de Linux.

Comment: Lo pudiste resolver?. La versión de WSL es importante. La versión 1 tiene un problema con el autoporting (No recuerdo bien el nombre), y es necesario actualizar la distro a WSL2

Comment: Saludos @Legna. Te comento que este era un proyecto que heredé, no lo cree yo y me comentaron que se creo desde el entorno de Windows y, hay veces que dentro del package-lock.json, queda guardado esta configuración por lo que a veces no es muy amigable con otros entornos. Yo no tenía idea de esto pero, lo pude comprobar creando un proyecto nuevo desde el entorno de Linux y me funcionó sin ningún inconveniente así que sí podría ser esa la razón.
P.D.: Utilizo la versión 2 de WSL.